# AngularJS - can't read the URL parameter

Tags: angularjs

in my `stateProvider` definition I have:

```
return function ( $stateProvider ) {
    return $stateProvider.state('welcomeCAReg', {
                                url:         '/myURL/:id',
                                templateUrl: 'hi.html',
                                controller:  'hiController'
                         })
```

and then, in the controller I want to read the `:id` param:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode().enabled = true;
....
var paramValue = $location.search().id;
```

but the `paramValue` value is undefined, why ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`$stateParams`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#basic-parameters) service:

```
function hiController($stateParams) {
    console.log( $stateParams.id )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up by using

```
$state.params['id'];
```

which works